# Passthrough Windows AD authentication with LAMP GSSAPI/Kerberos

Tags: active-directory, lamp, passthrough, gssapi

Trying to stand up a LAMP server on a Windows AD and get passthrough authentication working.  One gotcha (which may not be as big of a deal as I'm making it), the hostname and hosted URL do NOT match: LAMP hostname is `intranethost.mspca.org`, hosted URL is `https://testintranet.mspca.org`

AD is forest/domain level 2012R2.

LAMP is Debian 11.8 with mod_auth_gssapi installed with Apache.  The LAMP does NOT have Samba installed, and is NOT a member of the AD domain (wasn't sure if that was necessary).

Created a keyspan file from the Windows DC with the following:

`ktpass -princ HTTPS/testintranet.mspca.org@MSPCA.ORG -mapuser adconnect@MSPCA.ORG -pass ******** -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out testintranet-spn.keytab`

My realm is added correctly into krb5.cnf, kinit from the LAMP passes with flying colors.

Apache conf (based on a tutorial at https://www.jfcarter.net/%7Ejimc/documents/bugfix/41-auth-kerb.html):

```
<IfModule !mod_auth_gssapi.c>
    LoadModule auth_gssapi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_gssapi.so
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName testintranet.mspca.org
#       Redirect permanent / https://testintranet.mspca.org/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/star_mspca_org.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/star_mspca_org.key
        ServerAdmin jsinclair@mspca.org
        ServerName testintranet.mspca.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/

        <Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress/">
                AllowOverride All
                AuthType GSSAPI
                AuthName "GSSAPI Single Sign On Login"
                GssapiSSLonly On
                GssapiAllowedMech krb5
                GssapiBasicAuth On
                GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/apache2/testintranet-spn.keytab
                GssapiLocalName On
                BrowserMatch Windows gssapi-no-negotiate
                Require valid-user
                GssapiNegotiateOnce on
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpress.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpress.access.log combined
        LogLevel info auth_gssapi:debug ssl:warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The authentication itself is in fact working, but I still get the initial login prompt for the site.  It's not carrying the currently logged in creds over to the session.  I've added every permutation of the site (http/s, short name, FQDN) into a GPO for the Intranet security-level page, but chrome is still stubbornly displaying the login dialog.  Only 'error' in the Apache logs is the ever-helpful `NO AUTH DATA Client did not send any authentication headers`

Flipping `GssapiBasicAuth` to OFF eliminates the dialog, but I immediately get a 401 Unauthorized, so it's like it isn't even *trying* to pass the headers...

Any suggestions?

Comment: If Chrome is not sending a W3 auth header with a Kerberos token from the logged on session in response to the 401, you may want to try the Chrome specific GPOs in the following article.  https://specopssoft.com/blog/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for-windows-integrated-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

This little guy:

`BrowserMatch Windows gssapi-no-negotiate`

I swear, I saw on *multiple sites* "if you don't have this line, Windows clients won't work..."

I took that line **out**, now it works 100% as expected.  The authentication passes through from the currently logged in Windows users (through Chrome to a FQDN internal host) just fine.

Just in case some future Google search leads someone here...